# Algebra to add numerator to logarithm

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I want to subtract two fractions $$\frac1{n\log(\frac n3)} \text{ and } \frac{c}{n\log(n)}.$$ Looking at a solutions manual I have the end result has the denominator $n\log(\frac n3)$.

My question is what can I add to the second equation $\frac c{n\log(n)}$ to put its denominator at $n\log(\frac n3)$ because when I try to make the denominator $n\log(n)\log(\frac n3)$ I never end up at the final answer which has only $n\log(\frac n3)$ in the denominator.

Comment: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac{1}{n\log(n/3)}-\frac{c}{n\log n}=\frac{\log n-c\log(n/3)}{n\log(n/3)\log n}=\frac{(1-c)\log n+c\log 3}{n\log (n/3)\log n}=\frac{1-c+{c\log_n 3}}{n\log(n/3)}$$